# Information given to a patient when he or she is diagnosed with a disorder

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the information given to a patient when he or she is diagnosed with a disorder? What would a native speaker call such information? "Initial information"?

Comment: You mean diagnosis?

Comment: What sort of information?

Comment: Yeah, why isn't it "diagnosis"?

Comment: What information?

Answer (score 3):

Everything you tell them is called **"patient information"**, which, depending on what they have (acute, sub-acute, or chronic condition, etc) includes their diagnosis, the natural history of their disorder, treatment and prognosis.

Comment: It's hard to argue with the label, but in the US, patient information is usually ancillary to the diagnosis or the medication. For example, with someone diagnosed with pneumonia and placed on, say, Zithromax, the physician will ask the discharge nurse to give the patient a patient information sheet on pneumonia and antibiotics. It's like a commonly-asked-question type of thing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is additional information given to the patient and his or her family when the patient is diagnosed. Information that is of interest at an early stage and that is provided by an ngo (broschures and in this case a toy). An initial information package provided to children diagnosed with JIA?